# .net Castle Windsor how to specify component property to constructor parameter in xml?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I can't figure out how to pass a compoment property to a constructor parameter.

```
<component id="NotificationCenterManager"
                     service="Advise.Notification.INotificationCenterManager, Xsquare"
                     type="Advise.Notification.NotificationCenterManager, Xsquare">        
</component>    
<component id="JobProcessorConfigurationSender"
                 service="Advise.Core.JobProcessor.IJobProcessorConfigurationSender, Advise.Core"
                 type="Advise.JobProcessorManagement.JobProcessorConfigurationSender, Xsquare">
      <parameters>
            <notificationCenterUri>${NotificationCenterManager.NotificationCenterUri}
</notificationCenterUri>
      </parameters>
</component>
```

Where NotificationCenterUri is a property of interface INotificationCenterManager.
At the moment ${NotificationCenterManager.NotificationCenterUri} is treated like a literal...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windsor does not provide that out of the box. You'd have to write a [facility](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/concepts/facility.html) to implement it. However, I wouldn't recommend it: by doing this you're implicitly making JobProcessorConfigurationSender depend on NotificationCenterManager (implicitly because it's not anywhere in the source code of JobProcessorConfigurationSender).

Instead, consider putting this URI as a [property](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.XML-configuration-properties.ashx), then reference it in the component configuration of NotificationCenterManager and JobProcessorConfigurationSender.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The problem is the URI is dynamic and depends of the machinename.
Would you have any other suggestions ?
Thanks

Comment: @Pierre-Louis: if you have to do this in XML, you could create a IUriProvider service that provides this information, then use that service in NotificationCenterManager and JobProcessorConfigurationSender

Comment: @Pierre-Louis: another option would be writing a ISubDependencyResolver or a IContributeComponentModelConstruction

Comment: I guess I will do that.
Thanks